# Solace Client JMS : Operation Not supported on Router: Router doesn't support transacted sessions

Tags: spring, jms, solace

I am trying to listen to a Solace End Point using Sping Boot and when ran my app i am getting the Error:

```
2018-09-28 03:16:57.446  WARN 27305 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'TEST1.OUT' - trying to recover. Cause: Error creating session - operation not supported on router (Capability Mismatch: Router does not support transacted sessions.)
```

Is there a config argument that i can set to not to use transaction sessions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a `JmsListenerContainerFactory` that does not make use of transactions. For example:

```
@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory listenerFactory =
            new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(listenerFactory, connectionFactory);
    listenerFactory.setTransactionManager(null);
    listenerFactory.setSessionTransacted(false);
    return listenerFactory;
}
```

Full details can be found in the [spring boot docs](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/howto.adoc#disable-transacted-jms-session).

---

Do note that the Solace message broker supports transactions(local and XA).

To enable local transactions:

1. Enable `allow‑transacted‑sessions` in the client-profile used by your username.
2. Disable `direct transport` in your JMS connection factory.

Full details can be found in the [Solace documentation](https://docs.solace.com/Solace-JMS-API/Using-Transacted-Sessions.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent answer.

To complement Russell answer, in the method which will handle the consume, in the annotation, we must specify the container factory bean created in the last step.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "TOPIC.TRX_PAYMENT", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
```